# Git issue with committed file

Tags: github

I have a `200MB` zip file in my source directory. That file was committed mistakenly. After two days try I removed it from the repository and pushed my files again. That worked at that time.
Today After a month I am having the same issue. the global.zip despite of it being deleted earlier. 
Now I can't remove it from my repository it is causing me headache, please help me.

```
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4987/4987), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5074/5074), 189.02 MiB | 4.17 MiB/s, done.
Total 5074 (delta 985), reused 0 (delta 0)
efrror: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
atal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I run `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf public/assets/global.zip' HEAD`

I got this error:

```
Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.` should give you the idea of the problem. You have still changes in your files that are not yet committed to your repository. commit these changes or revert them then the git filter branch will work.